# Using F# List.sort with a type that has CustomComparison

Tags: f#

I am trying to define a type in F# that has an id and a value, and when sorting only the value is considered.  I have simplified the situation to make a hopefully clear example.

I have the following so far:

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type EquatableValue<'T when 'T : comparison> = 
    { id : string; value : 'T }

    override x.Equals(yobj) = 
        match yobj with
        | :? EquatableValue<'T> as y ->
            x.value = y.value
        | _ -> false

    override x.GetHashCode() = 
        hash x.value

    interface System.IComparable with
        member x.CompareTo yobj = 
            match yobj with
                | :? EquatableValue<'T> as y ->
                    compare x.value y.value
                | _ -> invalidArg "yobj" "cannot compare values of different types" 

let a = {id="a";value=5}  
let b = {id="b";value=4}
let c = {id="c";value=7}
let d = {id="d";value=1}

let x = [a,b,c,d]  

let sorted = x |> List.sort
```

I would expect the elements of `sorted` to be in the order (by id) d, b, c, a.

But this results in the order a, b, c, d.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) with the int as the key to be sorted and the string as the value?

Comment: I'm using a custom comparison because the objects will be in a deedle frame, so this will allow me to sort the rows of the frame without specifying a sorting function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your list contains only one element - tuple consisting of 4 values:

```
let x = [a,b,c,d]
```

use

```
let x = [a;b;c;d]
```

because elements of list are divided by `';'`

Comment: Thank you, rather embarrassing to miss that!  Cheers.